# Can i use cloudwatch to download all the logs of a set time frame?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Cloudwatch is really bad, so I'm just going to get the logs for the timeframe I need and post-process it.

How can I do this? ie download a text or whatever file of the logs for a set timeframe?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

```
aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name my-group [--log-stream-names LIST_OF_STREAMS_TO_SEARCH] [--start-time 1482197400000] [--end-time 1482217558365] [--filter-pattern VALID_METRIC_FILTER_PATTERN]
```

More [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SearchDataFilterPattern.html)